# Is possible convert HTML into pdf using Zend_Pdf?

Tags: html, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

Is possible convert **directly** HTML into a pdf file using Zend_Pdf?, if so, How can I do that?

Comment: Nope, I don't think this is what it was built for. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.introduction.html

Comment: Although this might be Frankenstein-ish (and not really an answer to your question) I've used PHP to generate content, send the output buffer to a file, and used _wkhtmltopdf_ to generate PDFs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Zend_PDF` isn't able to generate PDF based on HTML. But you can render view and use other library for convert it to PDF. I've done such thing with [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Little code snippet below:

```
    //SomeController.php
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    //set content for view here

    // create new PDF document        
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); 

    //whole TCPDF's settings goes here

    $htmlcontent = $this->view->render('recipe/topdf.phtml');
    // output the HTML content
    $pdf->writeHTML($htmlcontent, true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->lastPage();
    $pdf->Output("pdf-name.pdf", 'D');
```

Comment: Is there a chance you could go into more detail of an example of what somecontroller.php would be, and what goes in 'set content for view here'? Thanks!

Comment: @joren It's the exact same way in which you create normal controllers in ZF: `SomeController extends Zend_Controller_Action`. Same with view: `$this->view->foo = 'bar'`. Whole trick is to render page as normal ZF page, but instead outputing it into screen, you catch this into variable `$htmlcontent` and pass to TCPDF `writeHTML()` method.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up working around it a different way, bu this help.

Comment: like the approach but didn't work for me since i need to pass variable in the view via <code>$this->view->entities= $entities</code>
All i got it the first th column... Any Hint?

Comment: sorry it was about unclosed tags

Answer (score 2):

tcpdf is a little limited when it comes to html, [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) uses webkit

Comment: The question is regarding zend_pdf for which tcppdf, dompdf and mpdf are more sutiable.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) . The ultimate one. Create your html with inline css, store it in one php variable and echo to pdf file. you are done!!!

Answer (score 1):

i've used dompdf https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf its pretty easy and straight forward. it even reads/formats css.

Comment: I tried to use dompdf for generating pdf from html, but it has a really annoying (known) issue: it puts a few empty pages between two table rows (at least in 0.6.0 beta 3)