# Zend_Pdf letter-spacing

Tags: zend-framework, zend-pdf

Is there a possibility in Zend_Pdf to increase the letter spacing? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [Is possible convert HTML into pdf using Zend_Pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183238/is-possible-convert-html-into-pdf-using-zend-pdf)

and later realize that you need CSS to increase [letter spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @KarmicDice,

I've read through this post, but this is more about converting HTML to PDF. In my case i want to increase the space between the characters "just like CSS letter-spacing". I can't seem to find how this is done with Zend_Pdf in the link you post.

Comment: use CSS... I have used fpdf for few projects where I have let CSS handle the letter spacing and I would embed it as a style attr of the DOM element... which was easier :) Works for you?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no pitch control in `Zend_Pdf` - it is reliant upon the glyph widths in the font definition. Having said that, I don't remember it being an option in `FPDF` or `TCPDF` either.